# Bad request 400 error while acessing wcf rest service frequently

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, iis-7.5

I am facing the problem of Bad request 400 while accessing the wcf service. I have tried all the solution related to this topic but still not solved. Wcf service is on IIS7 .

I am trying to call the service with below code.

```
try
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            byte[] data = client.DownloadData(ApplicationRunTimeSettings.ServiceURL() + userID);
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream(data);

            DataContractJsonSerializer obj = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(string));
            result = obj.ReadObject(stream).ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }


        return result;
```

The config file at service is below, the config file is same for the wcf as well as web application. Actually wcf service is developed with in the web application and the web app hosted on iis7 and we are accessing the service with in it.

The configuration file is below. Most of the time it does not return error but it is breaking after some time. Request on the wcf service is frequent . Data is form of JSON.

---

Now after making the below suggested changes for serviceThrottling the web.config file look like mentioned below but it still gives the same error some times.

```
 <system.web>
<sessionState timeout="1440"/>
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="90" maxRequestLength="104857600" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" minFreeThreads="8" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" appRequestQueueLimit="100" enableVersionHeader="true"/>
<!--set compilation defug="false" when releasing-->
<compilation targetFramework="4.0" >
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="86400"/>
</authentication>
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
  </namespaces>
</pages>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <!-- maxAllowedContentLength = bytes -->
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600"/>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
<system.serviceModel>

<services>
  <service name="Glance.DynamicBusinessService.DynamicBusinessService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
    <endpoint address="customBinding" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicConfig" contract="Glance.DynamicBusinessService.IDynamicBusinessService"/>
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Glance.DynamicBusinessService.IDynamicBusinessService" behaviorConfiguration="REST">
      <!--
          Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the
          identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity
          automatically.
      -->
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="throttleThis">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
      <serviceThrottling
          maxConcurrentCalls="40"
          maxConcurrentInstances="20"
          maxConcurrentSessions="20"/>

      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="REST">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>

  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="999999999" receiveTimeout="24" closeTimeout="24" maxBufferPoolSize="999999999" maxBufferSize="999999999">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="999999999" maxArrayLength="99999" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="99999" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>

  <customBinding>
    <binding name="basicConfig">
      <binaryMessageEncoding/>
      <httpTransport transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864"/>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0"/>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Thanks for any suggestion and help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to comment out that  configuration line on the client and host, and then trying running it. That config seems to set minimums and performance limits. If that doesn't change anything, you might try setting the performance throttling.

You could add this to the configuration and tinker with the settings until the performance of your web service smooths out. The default, for instance, for concurrent calls is 16, but if you raise that number using the ServiceThrottling, you might get better results.

```
<serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="throttleThis">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
            <serviceThrottling
                maxConcurrentCalls="40"
                maxConcurrentInstances="20"
                maxConcurrentSessions="20"/>
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
```

Comment: Hi Brian Thanks for your suggestion But still it gives the bad request error some times. I have edit the my config file above with your changes. You can have a look.

Comment: These kinds of problems are not easy to debug. You might try using fiddler as a proxy to capture the messages going back and forth between the host and client. Also, turn on the logging.